# Reduce GoLand's editor's left margin width/padding

Tags: intellij-idea, ide, jetbrains-ide, goland

Accidentally, by pressing an unknown combination of keys, something weird has happened to my GoLand IDE configuration, and now the space that wraps the line numbers in the left column of the editor tabs has became just too wide.

I've tried looking for a option in the settings that allow me to configure this, but without any success. Do someone know what has happened and how can I restore my previous setup?

[image]

Comment: Doesn't it help to close all editor tabs and reopen them?

Comment: I'm afraid not...

Comment: @beni0888 It's interesting that you have the run gutter icon on the struct. What version of GoLand are you using (`Help | Find Action | About`)? Are you using any 3rd-party plugins?

Comment: the reason behind that is because the struct represents a Testify's test suite, and Goland identifies it that way

Comment: Looks like https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-198117. But reopening editor tab should refresh gutter width. Do you use any custom plugins?